# Cannot set date on UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I have a DatePicker in my application which I use to select date (UIDatePickerModeDate). Below is desired behavior

1. When user makes a selection I save the value in NSDate member variable so that I can set that value when needed.
2. Once the user makes a selection he can move to next view. If the user comes back to datepicker view then UIDatePicker should show previous selection.

Now I am simulating following situation

1. User makes a selection (lets say Feb 21,2017) which sets a value to my member variable.
2. Now he spins the year wheel and while its spinning move to next screen/view.
3. When user navigates back to DatePicker view, I set the UIDatePicker date to Feb 21, 2017 which is previous selection but I see a different value.

I don't know what am I missing. All I want is to set a value on UIDatePicker. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Here is code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     [self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(onWheelSpin) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

-(void)onWheelSpin {
    [self setSelectedDate:[self.datePicker date]];
    NSLog(@"Selected date = %@",self.datePicker.date.description);
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if(self.selectedDate) {
        //after setting the selectedDate, I see that some random date is shown in Picker
        [self.datePicker setDate:self.selectedDate];
    } else {
        [self.datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I understand, the issue is that the datePicker does not get set to "Feb 21,2017" when you return to your view. What happens when you set `datePicker.date = savedDate` in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @Prientus I do set the savedDate on viewWillAppear but nothing it still shows some other random date. I have added code snippet.

Comment: when user do scroll and move to next page, it will automatically set it again with the new values. Reason, It calls the "onWheelSpin" method due to datepicker value get changed after scroll.

Comment: @RajeshS "onWheelSpin" doesn't get called if I move to next page if the wheel is still spinning. I don't see the log statement and also 'selectedDate' is set to previous selection.

Comment: Are you sure that `viewWillAppear:`is actually called? As far as I know, it is called only when it the view is added to the view hierarchy. So if you present another view e.g. modally and go back, this method won't be called, and the date won't be set.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner yes viewWillAppear is getting called when I go back to DatePicker View.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner, you are wrong about viewWillAppear:. It is called any time a view controller is completely covered by another one, and then returned to the screen (modal presentation and navigation controller pushes being the 2 main examples.)

Comment: @Duncan Thanks for clarification. I just remembered the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear) "This method is called before the view controller's view is about to be added to a view hierarchy" and "If a view controller is presented by a view controller inside of a popover, this method is not invoked on the presenting view controller after the presented controller is dismissed."

Comment: True. Note that I said "It is called any time a view controller is completely covered by another one..." A popover doesn't completely cover the presenting view controller, so that's an exception.